# Using Entity Framework Code First Development, can I get it to create a table or tables in an existing database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to Entity Framework, and I have an existing database that I'd like to add a few tables to, rather than creating a database from scratch for my new tables. Is this possible with Entity Framework?

I've looked through the following MSDN articles on Code First development, and haven't been able to find the answer to my issue:

[Code First Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh770082%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

[Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161541%28v=vs.103%29)

[Code First Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844%28v=vs.103%29)

[Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28v=vs.103%29)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same experience with my asp.net mvc3 project, it's a little different from asp.net but I guess entity framework is the focus here.

1. create new table in sql server
2. create corresponding model in your model project
3. Add the new table object property in DbNameEntities.cs

   public DbSet NewTables { get; set; }
4. In Application_Start() method, comment out the original code first approach

   System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new SeedSampleData());

replace with this:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<DbNameEntities>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible.

A decent walk-through is available [on Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)